# iframe not executing Javascript method (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm having some trouble submitting multiple files in a form in PHP.

This code is working on localhost and one one of my servers running PHP 5.4, I'm working with Laravel framework. I'm trying to make it work in a server running PHP 5.6 (don't know if that's the problem).

I have a simple form with a multiple input file upload, when the on change event of this input is fired, I submit the form targeting it to an iframe, so I can have a response when the file upload finishes:

My form:

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:100;height:100;border:0px solid #fff; ;"></iframe>
            <form action="{{URL::route('uploadsmallgalleryimage')}}" id="uploadSmallGalleryImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
              <input name="files[]" id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
            </form>
```

This form is executed on a method, does all the uploading files stuff, which is working perfect, but when it finishes, I need to call a javascript method from the parent, this is what is not working, it seems not to be working any javascript call, I have even tried to make a simple alert("message"); and still not doing anything.

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("upload_target").contentWindow.finish();
        </script>';
```

Comment: you are doing right echo '<script .....  </script>' try one instead doing this. you close php tag and then put your javascript code. 
Also, if you want to call parent function 
then call like this   parent.yourfunctioanname(); or window.parent.yourfunctioanname()

Comment: Still don't know why, the problem was the server, I changed my code to another server and working fine... Weird...

Comment: Post your full code so that anyone can check it thoroughly, if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Edit Succesful')</script>";
```